# Pattern Match in python

Tags: python, regex

I have given snippet of output string as below:

```
1b   16 PM1733A_384_SED   S657NE0R400049   MPP94E5Q  12   0    1BF1F72B0  99.9%   0208  Samsung PM1733a 3.84TB 1-WPD-SED

2b   17 PM1733_384_SED    LPNE0M900631     EPK9DE5Q --EMT--    1BF1F72B0   0.0%   0208  Samsung PM1733 3.84TB 1-WPD-SED

1b   18 PM1733A_30T_SED   S6UANE0RB00321   MPP95E5Q --PNP--    DAFA00000   0.0%   0208  Samsung PM1733a 30.72TB 1-WPD-SED  Discovered PNP

2b
```

I wanted to create a pattern that will match the above output.

If you see column [6,7] in first line, the output is '12 0'. In second line, the output is '--EMT--' in column 6 and in third line it is --PNP--. I am able to create pattern for first or second/third line separately. But is there way we can create on pattern for 3 lines?

```
pattern = r'\s+\d\w\s+[0-9A-F]*\s+[A-Z0-9]*_[A-Z0-9]*_[A-Z]*\s+[A-Z0-9]*\s+[A-Z0-9]*\s+[0-9]*\s+[0-9]\s+[A-Z0-9]*\s+[0-9][0-9].[0-9]%\s+[0-9]{4}\s+[A-Za-z]*\s+'
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a regexp for this? Looks like it ciuld be easier to use steing.split and rule based processing.

Comment: Also, do you know which kind of values you can expect for the columns? For example, if 0 is a valid value for the column with 1BF1F72B0, the result is ambigious.

Comment: Yes, I have used split new line option and able to get this lines. But from regexp, is it possible to get 'pattern' for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the first 3 lines to the part where your pattern only matches the first line (without the leading and trailing whitspace chars):

```
\b\d\w\s+[\dA-F]+\s+[A-Z\d]+_[A-Z\d]+_[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z\d]+\s+[A-Z\d]+\s+(?:\d+\s+\d+|--[A-Z]+--)\s+[A-Z0-9]+\s+\d+\.\d%\s+\d{4}\s+[A-Za-z]+\b
```

The added part matches:

- `(?:` Non capture groups for the alternatives

  - `\d+\s+\d+` Match 1+ digits, 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `--[A-Z]+--` Match 1+ chars A-Z between `--`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSuu1u/1).

**Note** that in your pattern you use quantifiers like `*` and in that case it can match zero or more times, so `_[A-Z0-9]*_` would also allow for `__` to match.